# Añadir un contador a un documento de texto

Tags: c++

Tengo que poner un contador en la parte de arriba de un documento .txt, que cuente partidas guardadas.

```
void guardaPartidas(const tListaPartidas& partidas) {
    string nombre;
    cout << "Ingresa el nombre del archivo de guardado: ";
    cin >> nombre;
    
    ofstream archivoEd(nombre, std::ios::app);

    if (archivoEd.is_open()) {
        
        //archivoEd << partidas.contador;
        guardaTablero(partidas.partidas[1].tablero, archivoEd);
        archivoEd << partidas.partidas[1].turno << endl;
        guardaJugadores(partidas.partidas[1].estadoJug, archivoEd);
        archivoEd.close();           
        
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO SE PUDO GUARDAR EL ARCHIVO" << endl;
    }
}
```

Tengo esto que me guarda las partidas en el documento de texto, pero necesito que ponga un contador en la parte de arriba que aumente cuando se guarda una nueva partida, he intentado hacer que lea primero el documento ya que el contador esta en la primera linea, y una vez leido aumentarlo en uno y añadir la partida.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes insertar caracteres en un archivo, solo agregar nuevos al final o modificar los que ya existen.

Por lo tanto, tendrás que cargar en memoria el contenido del archivo, modificarlo y guardarlo. Reescribirlo desde el comienzo en definitiva.

Teniendo en cuenta esa limitación una alternativa consiste en escribir un número de dígitos suficientemente grande. El archivo se vería así:

> 00000000
>
> Resto del archivo

De modo que al guardar una partida el número aumente así: **00000001**, **00000002**, **00000003**, etc.

Puedes conseguirlo combinando las funciones [`setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) para definir un caracter de relleno y [`setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) para definir un número de caracteres como mínimo.

Así imprimiría un número rellenando con 0 los dígitos que falten hasta llegar a 6:

```
archivoEd << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(6) << numero;
```

[Aquí](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCVVwSYzv7ikKDUx144LWSw3MS@zwI6LKzOvRCE3MTNPQ1OhmksBCEACeQq2CoZGxtZggeKSFCur5PzSEgUbGwinOLUkLTMnR0PdQF0TWbBcwwzMz7Pmqv3/HwA) se muestra como se vería con `cout`.

Entonces, luego de guardar las partidas, vas al inicio del archivo con [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) y escribes el número de partidas. Así:

```
guardaTablero(partidas.partidas[1].tablero, archivoEd);
archivoEd << partidas.partidas[1].turno << endl;
guardaJugadores(partidas.partidas[1].estadoJug, archivoEd);
archivoEd.seekg(0);
archivoEd << setfill('0') << setw(6) << numero;
archivoEd.close();
```

Recuerda que, en este caso, como se rellenan hasta 6 caracteres solo podrás guardar **999999** partidas. Puedes cambiar el 6 por un 7 y se guardarán hasta **9999999**. Pero si intentas guardar una partida más, ya estarías pisando la información de la primera partida.

---

En lugar de guardar el número como texto, también podrías guardarlo en binario y aprovecharías mejor el espacio. Para eso puedes usar la función [`write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) de la siguiente manera:

```
guardaTablero(partidas.partidas[1].tablero, archivoEd);
archivoEd << partidas.partidas[1].turno << endl;
guardaJugadores(partidas.partidas[1].estadoJug, archivoEd);
archivoEd.seekg(0);
archivoEd.write((char*)&numero, sizeof(numero));
archivoEd.close();
```

Comment: En el caso en el que el maximo de partidas que se pueden guardar en el archivo de texto sea de 10.  

`if(numero < 10){
archivoEd << numero;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Mateo te ha dado una solución a lo que necesitas hacer, utilizando ese algoritmo he preparado lo siguiente:

```
const int MAXPARTIDAS= 10;

struct Partida{
    Tablero     tablero;
    int         turno;
    EstadoJug   estadoJug;
};
void guardarTablero(const Tablero &t, ostream &streamSalida);
void guardarPartida(const Partida &partida, ostream &streamSalida);
void guardarEstadoJug(const EstadoJug &estadoJug, ostream &streamSalida);

struct ListaPartidas{
    Partida partidas[MAXPARTIDAS];
    int numPartidas;
};
```

La siguiente función trata de leer el numero de partidas que esta al inicio del fichero, si no encuentra el fichero trata de crearlo y escribir en él el numero de partidas inicial que será de 0.

```
bool leerNumeroPartidas(const string &nombreFichero, int &numPartidas){
    ifstream streamEntrada(nombreFichero);
    if(!streamEntrada.is_open()){
        ofstream streamSalida(nombreFichero);
        numPartidas= 0;
        streamSalida<<setw(3)<<right<<numPartidas<<endl;
        return streamSalida.good();
    }
    streamEntrada>>numPartidas;
    return streamEntrada.good();
}
```

La siguiente función abre el fichero, se posiciona al final, escribe el contenido de 'partida' en el fichero. Mueve el cursor de escritura al principio para escribir el numero de partidas incrementado en uno, sobreescribe el valor anterior y hace flush para asegurar que se ha escrito.

```
bool agregarPartidaA(const Partida &partida, const string &nombreFichero){
    int numPartidas;
    if(!leerNumeroPartidas(nombreFichero, numPartidas)){
        cout<<"No es posible leer - crear fichero '"<<nombreFichero<<"'"<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(numPartidas>= MAXPARTIDAS){
        cout<<"Numero de partidas maximo permitido en '"<<nombreFichero<<"'"<<endl;
        return false;
    }

    ofstream streamSalida(nombreFichero, ios::ate | ios::in);
    if(!streamSalida.is_open()){
        cout<<"Error al abrir '"<<nombreFichero<<"' para agregar partida."<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    guardarTablero(partida.tablero, streamSalida);
    streamSalida<<partida.turno<<'\n';
    guardarEstadoJug(partida.estadoJug, streamSalida);
    streamSalida.seekp(0);
    streamSalida<<setw(3)<<numPartidas+ 1<<flush;
    return streamSalida.good();
}
```

Esta es la función cliente, tiene casi la misma estructura que la función que necesitas implementar.

```
void guardaPartidas(const ListaPartidas& partidas) {
    string nombre;
    int indice;
    cout << "Ingresa el nombre del archivo de guardado: ";
    cin >> nombre;
    cout<<"Ingrese el indice de partida a guardar: ";
    cin >> indice;

    if(agregarPartidaA(partidas.partidas[indice], nombre)){
        cout<<"La partida "<<indice<<" se ha guardado correctamente."<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Error al guardar partida."<<endl;
    }
}
```